# Find the radius increase to account for a segmented circle

Tags: geometry, area

I want to find the required radius increase in order to maintain circle area when the circle is segmented. Example below:
[image]

(please note the outer circle is off centre, it is meant to maintain the same central position as the inner circle)

I essentially want to find $R_2$. $R_2$ is chosen such that $A_1 + A_2 = \pi(R_1)^2$. The only unknowns are $R_2$ and $A_2$.

Does anyone know the standard way of doing this? The current way of going about it involves finding the segmented areas of the inner circle, to find what area is missing. But even then I'm not sure how to account for the fact that the new circle will also be segmented by these same lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to remember that we can parametrize a circle with radius $r$ centered at $(x_c, y_c)$ using
$$y(x) = y_c \pm \sqrt{r^2 - (x - x_c)^2} \quad \iff \quad x(y) = x_c \pm \sqrt{r^2 - (y - y_c)^2}$$

For simplicity, let's mirror the case so that $A_2$ is the area between the two circles *in the positive quadrant*, $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$.

Let the first circle be centered at $(x_1, y_1)$, $x_1 \ge 0$ and $y_1 \ge 0$, with radius $r_1 \ge x_1$ and $r_1 \ge y_1$.  Then, area $A_1$ is divided into four quadrants: one is a quarter of the circle, one is the rectangle between origin and the center of the circle, and two are rectangles with one side a circular arc:
$$A_1 = \frac{\pi}{4}r_1^2 + x_1 y_1 + \int_0^{y_1} \sqrt{r_1^2 - y^2} d x + \int_0^{x_1} \sqrt{r_1^2 - x^2} d y \tag{1a}\label{EQ1a}$$

That looks nasty, but when $0 \le X \le R$,
$$\int_0^X \sqrt{R^2 - x^2} d x ~ = ~  \frac{X}{2}\sqrt{R^2 - X^2} + \frac{r^2}{2}\operatorname{arcsin}\left(\frac{X}{R}\right)\tag{2}\label{EQ2}$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{aligned}
A_1 & = \frac{\pi}{4}r_1^2 ~ + ~ x_1 y_1 \\
~ & + \frac{x_1}{2}\sqrt{r_1^2 - x_1^2} ~ + ~ \frac{y_1}{2}\sqrt{r_1^2 - y_1^2} \\
~ & + \frac{r_1^2}{2}\left(\operatorname{arcsin}\left(\frac{x_1}{r_1}\right) + \operatorname{arcsin}\left(\frac{y_1}{r_1}\right)\right) \\
\end{aligned} \tag{1b}\label{EQ1b}$$

Let's assume the outer circle is concentric with the first one, with radius $r_2 \gt r_1$. The area $A_2$ is divided into three sections: one is a full quarter annulus, plus two ring sections between the two circular arcs:
$$\begin{aligned}
A_2 & = \frac{\pi}{4}\left(r_2^2 - r_1^2\right) \\
~ & + \int_0^{x_1} \sqrt{r_2^2 - x^2} - \sqrt{r_1^2 - x^2} d x \\
~ & + \int_0^{y_1} \sqrt{r_2^2 - y^2} - \sqrt{r_1^2 - y^2} d y \\
\end{aligned} \tag{3a}\label{EQ3a}$$
In this case, we can split each integrals into two, and use $\eqref{EQ2}$. We get
$$\begin{aligned}
A_2 & = \frac{\pi}{4}\left(r_2^2 - r_1^2\right) \\
~ & + \frac{x_1}{2}\left(\sqrt{r_2^2 - x_1^2} - \sqrt{r_1^2 - x_1^2} \right) \\
~ & + \frac{y_1}{2}\left(\sqrt{r_2^2 - y_1^2} - \sqrt{r_1^2 - y_1^2} \right) \\
~ & + \frac{r_2^2}{2}\left(\operatorname{arcsin}\left(\frac{x_1}{r_2}\right) + \operatorname{arcsin}\left(\frac{y_1}{r_2}\right)\right) \\
~ & - \frac{r_1^2}{2}\left(\operatorname{arcsin}\left(\frac{x_1}{r_1}\right) + \operatorname{arcsin}\left(\frac{y_1}{r_1}\right)\right) \\
\end{aligned}\tag{3b}\label{EQ3b}$$
Note that if the circles are not concentric, you get three to five segments between the two arcs instead (five integrals); it solves the exact same way, except that you have eight possible cases (depending on how the two centers are located with respect to each other; this here case, concentric, being the ninth case).

Unfortunately, it seems that solving $A_1 = A_2$ for $r_2$ does not yield a nice algebraic expression, so you'll have to find the answer numerically.

Geometrically, we can see that when $r_2$ increases, $A_2$ increases as well; it is just that the ratio of the increases varies in a way that is very hard to express algebraically.  Mathematically, we can say that $A_2$ is a monotonically increasing function of $r_2$ at $r_2 \gt r_1 \ge 0$.  This means that we can use a very efficient binary search algorithm to find $r_2$:

1. Start with $r_2 = 2 r_1$.
2. Calculate $A_2$.
3. If $A_2 \lt A_1$, double $r_2$, and repeat step 2.
4. If $A_2 = A_1$, you have found $r_2$, and are done.
5. Set $r_{min} = r_2 / 2$ and $r_{max} = r_2$.
6. Set $r_2 = \frac{r_{min} + r_{max}}{2}$, and calculate $A_2$.
7. If $A_2 \lt A_1$, set $r_{min} = r_2$, and go back to step 6.
   If $A_2 \gt A_1$, set $r_{max} = r_2$, and go back to step 6.
8. Found $r_2$, and are done.

If you know the precision at which you need $r_2$, add a test for that to step 6, to check if $r_{min}$ and $r_{max}$ are close enough, and if so skip to end.

If you know the precision at which you know the areas, add a test for that to step 6, checking if the two areas are close enough, and if so skip to end.

If you use floating-point numbers, at minimum you need to add a check to step 6, that verifies that $r_2 \ne r_{min}$ and $r_2 \ne r_{max}$ (i.e., that there is enough precision to split the range), and otherwise skips to end.

This converges nicely, adding one bit of precision at each iteration.

Comment: The binary search method is actually a really good idea and is a quick and easy way to find the required radius increase